# How to test whether the distribution of majors among grad students differ from that of incoming students?

Tags: distributions, self-study, chi-squared-test, independence

A university offers degrees in the following areas:

Arts/Science
Engineering
Business
Computer Science

Incoming freshmen apply for majors in Arts, Science, Engineering, Business, and Computer Science in a ratio of approx. 5:6:6:8. But many students change their major during the course of study. The university officials are interested in determining whether the distribution of majors among graduating students differs from that of incoming students. They took a random sample of 200 graduating students and classified them according to their majors. The distribution of grad students in this sample is given in the table:

```
                                 Major
                    Arts/Science    Engineering    Business    Computer Science   
Number of students:       60              30           60             50
```

Is the distribution of majors among grad students different from that of incoming students?

Comment: Arts, Science should be Arts & Science

Comment: So edit your question to fix it so it says what you intend. Please take a read of the `self-study` [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). With that in mind, what have you tried? What do you understand? Where, specifically does your problem lie?

Comment: To speed this up a little: This is a standard textbook-style chi-square goodness of fit question.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the expected values for this question? The answer to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45333/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test) goes over the calculation of the test statistic for this kind of problem (though in that case the ratio is 1:1:1:1 rather than 5:6:6:8).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is very old now, we can do a full answer. You can use a chisquared test, where the null hypothesis probabilities are computed from the incoming ratios.  We do this in R:

```r
incoming <- c(5, 6, 6, 8)
graduate <- c(60, 30, 60, 50)

chisq.test(graduate, p=incoming, rescale.p=TRUE)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  graduate
X-squared = 22.812, df = 3, p-value = 4.418e-05
```